# Use of deferred execution method in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, block

My purpose is as follows: I want to create a deferred calling method. I might need to create a block for this, but I'm not sure. Can you explain me how to create a block for this?

This is the code:

```
- (IBAction)buyItem:(id)sender {
    BOOL purchase = ... /*call purchase method use block*/
}
```

In this method I make a purchase and after the purchase has completed successfully I want to get result in my variable `purchase`.

To be more clear:

Step 1: Call the `buyItem` method.

Step 2: Wait for a response to the purchase (I've omitted the actual methods for the purchase)

Step 3: After the StoreKit object return a response about the purchase, write a value into the variable `purchase`.

Step 4: After writing the value into `purchase`, my method `buyItem` completes execution (go to the `}` and release).

My question is not about StoreKit specifically (meaning the StoreKit response method - this is an example only). The `purchase` variable is an example, too. For this variable I will use a data model and it will change after the deferred method executes.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need a block, but maybe a different kind than you're thinking about. You don't need a 'closure', you need a function that will block until it receives the response from the store kit/server.

You can just write a normal buyItem method, but inside you either make a synchronous call to store kit, or if that's not possible, you use threading techniques to achieve what you want. For example, you could wait on a condition variable and then signal it when the store kit call returns.

For both cases, you'll want to perform the 'buyItem' call on a thread other than the UI thread, otherwise your UI will freeze. Given that constraint (if you're even dealing with a UI), I would say this entire approach doesn't make sense. Instead, you'll want to launch the store kit call, set some indicator or spinner or something in your UI, and then when the store kit call returns, unset the spinner or whatever. Make sense?

Comment: Hello Colin! Yes this is great idea! Thanks for a good and complete answer!